# base64 substring in a sql query

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I'm using athena, in aws, to parse a bunch of log files. The criteria of the query is a base64 encoded sub-string. ("adId=eW0vMU0zeGE5NUE4NjcyLzYzNDgvalhkVGhkZmxfODQwS182NDB4MzYwLm1wNAo=%somejunk")

As far as I can tell there is no problem with this query.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM reporting."logs"
WHERE sc_status NOT LIKE '404'
        AND cs_cookie LIKE 'adId%'
        AND cs_uri_stem LIKE'%.m3u8'
        AND FROM_UTF8( from_base64( regexp_extract(cs_cookie, '(adId=)([^ ]+?)\%(.*)',2) ) ) LIKE '%mp4' limit 1 ;
```

It gives me the error INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Illegal base64 character 5f

A different version, using all the components, does not return an error and gives me the value that ends in mp4.

```
SELECT FROM_UTF8( from_base64( regexp_extract(cs_cookie, '(adId=)([^ ]+?)\%(.*)',2) ) ) 
FROM reporting."logs" 
WHERE sc_status NOT LIKE '404' 
    AND cs_cookie LIKE 'adId%' 
    AND cs_uri_stem LIKE'%.m3u8' limit 1 ;
```

The return value doesn't have anything really strange in it.

```
ym/1M3xa95A8672/6348/jXdThdfl_840K_640x360.mp4
```

Any ideas on why I would get an error or how to format this so it will work?

Comment: The base64 function is implemented as a direct passthrough to the built in Java Base64 encoding: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there were some unsafe characters because it was a url.

Had to replace some invalid base64 characters.

The working version

```
SELECT *
FROM reporting."logs"
WHERE sc_status LIKE '2__'
AND date(date) = current_date - interval '1' day
        AND cs_cookie LIKE 'adId%'
        AND cs_uri_stem LIKE'%ad.m3u8'
        AND FROM_UTF8( from_base64( replace(replace(regexp_extract(cs_cookie, '(adId=)([^ ]+?)\%(.*)',2), '_','/'),'-','+') ) ) LIKE '%mp4'
```